# Exctract DEM by list of vertex with GDAL

Tags: gdal, dem

How can I generate a DEM of an area given the vertex list of the polygon that includes it?

What I want to achieve is similar to the output of gdalwarp, eg:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te x_min y_min x_max y_max output_srtm.tif -te_srs EPSG:4326 output.tif
```

but not of a rectangle like this case but of a polygonal area, everything that is outside the polygon should be generate as nodata value.